# Gifs in Grepolis make my computer lag, any way to fix?

Tags: grepolis

I am playing the browser game Grepolis and there are a lot of moving gifs.

I sometimes play on my really old computer and it causes some lag.

Would any of you know anyway to make it low detail or turn off the animations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Google chrome there are 2 plugins that stop animated gifs from working

1. [Paused!](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lineaegmeiendabencimakjagjojcegk) This plugin stops all gifs from being animated although it doesnt work perfectly with gifs hosted on other domains than the site itself
2. [Stop gifs on escape](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/80588) drawback by using this plugin is that you need to press escape before it stops animating.

In Firefox - Type about:config and change the value of string image.animation_mode from normal to none.

In Internet Explorer - Tools -> Options -> Advance. Uncheck the box in Multimedia group that says "Play animations in web pages"

Source:

1. http://labnol.blogspot.nl/2007/08/how-to-stop-gif-image-animations-from.html
2. http://www.simplehelp.net/2011/08/04/how-to-disable-animated-gifs-in-google-chrome/

Comment: Thanks so much for that. I used the firefox method and it works brilliantly.